# Error when clicking to data grid empty cell

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to pass the value of data grid cell  into labels when I click the dg cell.

```
Dim rowview as datarowview

rv = datagrid1.selecteditem

Label1.content = rowview.row(0).tostring()
```

It successfully pass the value to my label but
 every time I click to empty dg cell my wpf app crashes.

Any idea why?

Comment: Need to check that it's not nothing first. Can't do Nothing.ToString().